# Multiple Calls to sizeof() in a Row

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct dgm_network_pkt {
    char    responder[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int     num;
    char    **neighbors;
};
```

The field `num` keeps track of how many character arrays have been allocated and are pointed to by `neighbors`.

Now I would like to construct a packet that contains a header then the struct, and send a UDP packet that contains within it this packet.  In order to accomplish this, I need to do a lot of pointer arithmetic, and a lot of calls to sizeof().  For instance, if my header is `enum header hdr;`, my buffer is `char *buf;` and the instance of my struct is `struct mystruct stc;`, I need to do the following (snippet):

```
buf = malloc(sizeof(stc.num * SIZEOF_EACH_ARRAY) + sizeof(hdr) + sizeof(stc.responder) + sizeof(int));

memcpy(buf, &hdr, sizeof(hdr)); /* Copy over header */
memcpy(buf + sizeof(hdr), &stc.responder, sizeof(stc.responder)); /* Copy 'responder' field */
memcpy(buf + dizeof(hdr) + sizeof(stc.responder), &stc.num, sizeof(int)); /* Copy num field */
```

Then a loop to copy over the character arrays pointed to by `neighbors` that again calls `sizeof()` multiple times with the same parameters.

If you care to look, here is the function I use to accomplish all of this for reference, but it's not necessary to answer my question, and might add confusion (with the added indirection).

```
int dismesh_compose_net_pkt(struct dgm_network_pkt *dismesh_sta, char **buf)
{
    int i;
    int pkt_size;
    enum dgm_header dgm_hdr;

    pkt_size = dismesh_sta->num * DISMESH_ETH_ADDR_STR + sizeof(dgm_hdr) 
        + sizeof(dismesh_sta->responder) + sizeof(int);

    dgm_hdr = NETWORK_STATUS_RESP;
    if ((*buf = malloc(pkt_size)) == NULL)
        return -1; 

    memcpy(*buf, &dgm_hdr, sizeof(dgm_hdr));
    memcpy(*buf + sizeof(dgm_hdr), &dismesh_sta->responder, sizeof(dismesh_sta->responder));
    memcpy(*buf + sizeof(dgm_hdr) + sizeof(dismesh_sta->responder), &dismesh_sta->num, sizeof(int));

    /* Copy contents of neighbors to buffer */
    for (i = 0; i < dismesh_sta->num; i++) {
        memcpy(*buf + sizeof(dgm_hdr) + sizeof(dismesh_sta->responder) + sizeof(int) + i * DISMESH_ETH_ADDR_STR,
                *(dismesh_sta->neighbors + i), DISMESH_ETH_ADDR_STR);
        DGM_LOG("Packed up neighbor %d\n", i); 
    }   

    return pkt_size;
}
```

Here it is:

I noticed that I use a lot of calls to `sizeof()` with the same parameter over and over: in copying over the contents of the struct to the buffer, in the size of each element, etc, etc.  Is there a better way to do this?  I was thinking I could have some #defines in my header file in which, say, I could do `#define OFFSET_RESPONDER sizeof(hdr)`, `#define OFFSET_NUM OFFSET_RESPONDER + sizeof(mystruct.responder)`, and `#define SIZE_HEADER sizeof(dgm_header)`, etc.  Would I notice a significant performance loss by leaving it like it is?  Does the compiler (in my case GCC) optimize this?  Do you think the readability would go down with #defines?  What's the best way of cleaning this code up?

Comment: There are no performance issues with `sizeof`, it's a compile time evaluation (except for C99's VLAs)

Comment: `sizeof()` can't be "called" - it's not a function. It's a keyword.

Comment: Well color me embarrassed. I probably should have done a little more homework before asking a question with such an obvious answer =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, so the compiler will translate that to a single number.

Second, take a look at the [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro; I think it'll do exactly what you need.

Comment: Awesome additional information!  That `offsetof` macro will very much come in handy since this struct is only a skeleton of what it will eventually become, and those `buf + sizeof(field1) + sizeof(field2) + sizeof(field3)... ` will quickly become too messy to deal with.  Thanks again!

Comment: @justynnuff Not only is adding up the individual field sizes messy, it's unreliable because of the potential for padding between fields.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof()` is not a function, it is evaluated during compilation phase. So, changing the many occurences of `sizeof(something)` by a `#define CONSTANT` should not change anything in term of performance, it could only change the time to compile but I think it's negligible.

The only significant aspect is the code readability. Both are fine for me, you decide.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is certainly going to optimize this.  I wouldn't sacrifice code-readability by scattering non-semantic magic tokens around the place.

You could check the compiler output to verify this, but there are just going to be constants everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The only situation when `sizeof` is evaluated at run-time is when it is applied to a Variable Length Array (VLA). In all other cases it is replaced with a compile-time constant. I.e. there's no overhead ion evaluating the same `sizeof` multiple times. It doesn't look too pretty in the code and might incur some maintenance overhead, but it does not affect performance.

Hiding these `sizeof` evaluation behind a macro won't really change anything performance-wise, since macros are simply textual substitutions. This meas that the actual code will look exactly the same to the compiler proper. Nevertheless, a thoughtful use of macros might actually improve the readability of  repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is a built-in prefix operator. It is evaluated at compile-time, unless its argument is a C99-style variable-length array. In the latter case it is evaluated at run-time.

Something worth noticing is that parenthesis around `sizeof` argument are required only for types. I.e. `sizeof(dismesh_sta->responder)` can be replaced with `sizeof dismesh_sta->responder`, which saves typing one character.

Comment: @MarkoKevac It is ` ` vs `()`.